# Minimum Bounding Rectangle calculation in Boost R-Tree

Tags: c++, boost, r-tree, mbr

Minimum Bounding Rectangles is a pre-requisite for R-Tree creation. What algorithm does Boost C++ library use for MBR creation given a set of points?

Comment: Your question is rather broad. The title of your question in google has many answers. [How to as a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the obvious one.

Iterate over the contents and store the minimum bounds.

That is O(n) and you can't do any better than O(n), at the same time the algorithm is as easy a it gets, so it will come with small constant factors, too.